# Is there any way to encode Multiple columns in a csv using base64 in Shell?

Tags: encoding, base64

I have a requirement to replace multiple columns of a csv file with its base64 encoding value which should be applied to some columns of the file but keep the first line unaffected as the first line contains the header of the file. I have tried out for 1 column as below but as I have given it to proceed after skipping the first line of the file it is not

```sh
gawk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|" } NR >=2 { cmd="echo  "$4" | base64 -w 0";cmd | getline x;close(cmd); print $1,$2,$3,x}' awktest
```

o/p:

```
12|A|B|Qw==         
13|C|D|RQ==  
36|Z|V|VQ==
```

Qs: It is not showing the header in the output. What should I do to make produce the header in the output? Also can I use any loop here to replace multiple columns?

input:

```
10|A|B|C|5|T|R                                     
12|A|B|C|6|eee|ff                        
13|C|D|E|9|dr|xrdd                       
36|Z|V|U|7|xc|xd
```

Required output:

```
10|A|B|C|5|T|R                          
12|A|B|encodedvalue|6|encodedvalue|ff                                  
13|C|D|encodedvalue|9|encodedvalue|xrdd                               
36|Z|V|encodedvalue|7|encodedvalue|xd
```

Is this possible? Have researched a lot but could not find a proper explanation. I am new to shell. Kindly help. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you comment on the tools you have available? Is it necessary to use gawk? It sounds like you want to do this using bash-style shell tools; is that necessary? Are you using bash specifically, or some other shell? (It's a good idea to include this information in your tags too.)

Comment: Hi,I do not have any other tool for the same. I need to do it as a part of my data processing  and only available option for me is bash. Isn't is possible in bash?

Comment: Certainly you can, it's just going to be harder than if you used some other language. Python would seem like a good choice for the job. If you're restricted to dedicated text-processing tools, awk/gawk is a fine choice, but not one that I can help troubleshoot :(

Comment: okay...Thanks your input...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just sequence conditionals. This may not be the best way of solving the header issue, but it's intuitive.

```
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|" } NR ==1 {print} NR >=2 { cmd="echo  "$4" | base64 -w 0";cmd | getline x;close(cmd); print $1,$2,$3,x}
```

As for using a loop to affect multiple columns... Loops in bash are hard. Awk is technically its own language, and may have a looping construct of it's own, IDK. But it's not clear you need a loop. If there's only a reasonable number of fields that need modifying, you can just parameterize the existing command (somehow) by the field index, and then pipe through however many instances of it. It won't be as performant as doing it all in a single pass of awk, but that's probably ok.

Comment: Thank you.Will try the header part.Regarding looping Actually I have 7 columns to be encoded by base 64 in original file. When trying to use multiple echo statement and pipelining it is getting all of values together...When i try to give different variables with getline also getting problem of invalid syntax..also i have total 52 columns which i have to print like mentioned in command above.So is it possible to write all the columns with each getline.Not very sure about the getline and cmd how it is working perticuarly.

Comment: I tried the header fix and it worked. Thanks a lot.But no luck on the for loop.